# In Commerce 2, has anyone gotten Sales Tax calculation to work with the "Limit by postal code" option?

Tags: commerce

We've been trying to get sales tax calculations to work to calculate a tax rate depending on the Shipping address postal code.

When we setup up a new tax rule and enter the zip code(s) that match that rate's district the tax is not calculated during checkout.

On the configuration screen we notice that it says:

**The tax type will be used if both the customer and the store belong to one of the territories.**

This seems odd and is probably the cause of the issue that we're having.

Why would the stores' address need to be in the zip code of the order's ship to address?

We thought we solved it be simply entering another territory to the tax rate that did not include any "Limit by postal code" but all this did is cause the tax rates to display if the State matched and it ignores the other 'limit by postal code' filters.

Are we missing something in the setup, or is this a severe limitation of how you can configure tax rates in Commerce 2 (you can only charge tax for the zip code that the store's address is located in)?

[image]

Comment: Generally speaking, the store's address determines your tax nexus. It's not a 1:1 match, because you may also have a warehouse in Georgia that requires you to collect GA sales tax in addition to FL. I think the current constraints represent an unhelpful mixing of determining store nexus vs. identifying customers within that nexus - for a site representing a single store, we could just be checking the customer's address for taxability. Let me invite bojanz to come comment further here, because there may be a workaround you can use in the meantime.

Comment: Thank you Ryan, any help or workarounds would be great. We've been racking our brains on this one for a couple of days.

Comment: I discussed it at length with Bojan in Slack yesterday, and he did say that the primary supported use case here is for rates to be defined within a single type and for a custom tax resolver plugin (i.e. custom module code) to determine which rates actually apply to which order. That's where Zip code checks would come into play, as right now the territory related conditions are operating at the tax type level across all defined rates for that territory. If we pointed you toward the relevant documentation / examples, would you be able to write custom code for this?

Comment: Ryan, thank you for looking into this. Yes, I would be able to write the custom code needed if you could point me to the documentation. I'm assuming you're saying the create tax rates per postal code (within a US state) would require writing a custom tax plugin, correct?

Comment: Yeah, the idea would be you'd define all of your tax rates here (7%, 7.25%, 8%, etc.) and then use a resolver to pair the precise rate to the correct Zip codes. (I understand Florida is one of those complicated states to assign taxes for. : ) Let me point Bojan this way again to see what the best docs for you to reference will be and we can make that an official answer on this question until we improve core support for rate level conditions.